# Gulp :: Error: View file not found: `default.html`

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have been using gulp with the following code in gylpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.paths = {
    src: 'public',
    dist: 'public/dist',
    tmp: '.tmp',
    views: 'views',
    www: "www"
};

require('require-dir')('./gulp');

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('buildapp');
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.start('serve');
});
```

on another machine it was working but after i moved to a new machine it stopped with the following Error:

```
Server running at: http://0.0.0.0:5001
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    Error: View file not found: `default.html`. Locations searched: [/Users/shayan/cool-project/.tmp/views/layout/default.html]
```